# Unable to draw imageview as overlay

Tags: android, imageview, overlay

Following is what my app has:

1. One ImageButton named addButton
2. One ImageView named imagePane
3. One Button called resetButton

I want to make sure that the imagePane is transparent, and appears over all other windows. However, though it becomes transparent (other windows are seen below my window), the touch events are still not passed through the imagePane, and to other windows below.

Currently the following is what I am doing:

1. Checking for overlay permissions
2. Once permissions to draw over other windows is given, then I obtain the WindowManager service, set the LayoutParams and addView to the window manager service with the layout parameters
3. Also read through something called dispatchTouchEvent and dispatchKeyEvent, and tried overriding dispatchTouchEvent to pass events to the windows below when a certain variable (global) is set to 1, and not passing events otherwise. But this did not work

In MainActivity, I am calling this function:

`checkDrawOverlayPermissions()`

The function has the following:

```
        /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            /** if not construct intent to request permission */
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            /** request permission via start activity for result */
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

In onActivityResult(), the following is there:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                        0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                                 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                                 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE;
                params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
                wm.addView(imagePane, params);

                break;
        }
```

Expected result: The window should be transparent and the keys should pass to the windows below

Actual result: The window is transparent, but the keys are not sent down